# ASP.NET Hide Home Page Extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I have used URL rewriting in my ASP.NET 4.0 project to achieve the URL routing. Here is a sample code from my Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("main", "Main", "~/Home.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("aboutUs", "About-Us", "~/AboutUs.aspx");
    ...//so on and so forth
}
```

I also added this to Application_BeginRequest to forward Home.aspx to Main in the same Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("Home.aspx"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Main");
    }
}
```

This way, any request that tries to go to "Home.aspx" will be routed to "Main", which happens only in the first load. The routing works for all pages in my project.

Now, when I publish my code to my website and launch the website, this is what the URL comes up:

```
www.MyWebSite.com/Main
```

How can I hide "Main" at the end of the URL and make it look like this:

```
www.MyWebSite.com
```

~ Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure Home.aspx as "default page" in the Web Server.

Comment: I did that but since in Application_BeginRequest I redirect to "Main" it shows Main in the URL. Should I completely delete Application_BeginRequest code?

Comment: Actually, it worked!!!! I removed the redirect in BeginRequest and set the default page as Home.aspx. Thank you!

Comment: Try with something like this:

routes.MapPageRoute("Default", new Route(string.Empty, new RouteHandler("~/Site/Home.aspx")));